# Correct way to stop an ASP.net application during configuration?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

I have an `ASP.net Core 6` web application that uses the classic `Startup` class to bootstrap and configure the app.

In the `.Configure()` method of the startup class I need to check for a certain condition and if it doesn't pass I need to terminate the application.

My question is: is there a "proper" way to do this? Should I just throw an exception, or is there a more elegant/graceful way?

Comment: @MohammadAghazadeh: Who said anything about "special conditions"? I said I have to check a condition, as in: `if(some_condition) { /* stop application */ }`

Comment: What do you mean by  *certain condition* ? Are there commercial and sales issues?I ask this question to provide a suitable solution

Comment: I would say that something going wrong in the `Configure` method is usually an exceptional situation so throwing an exception seems to be an appropriate approach.

Comment: Do you mean you want to know how to capture the exception when configure metho facing some issue?

Comment: @GuruStron: that's what I thought, I just wanted to make sure there wasn't a more "proper" way, but it makes sense to throw an exception if something goes wrong during initialization.

Comment: @BrandoZhang: I merely wanted to make sure that throwing an exception was the proper way to interrupt startup or if there is some specific method call that triggers a "graceful" shutdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm gonna assume throwing an exception is the correct approach, since nobody provided any alternative.